# C# getting variables from a CAST statement using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following input string:

```
String text = "Cast(@myvar AS datetime)";
```

Is there some way by which I could extract the variable and datatype used using regex?

Expected output:

```
name ='@myvar'
type ='datetime'
```

Comment: What is "CAST"?  You question seems to be far too specific; with only one example,  it is unclear what can vary and therefore unclear what is needed to extract the parts you want.  [For intstance, you could simply take substrings of **text** at fixed offsets, but that probably won't work in general]

Comment: Actually my end goal is to find all the Cast statements in an SQL file and replace them with Convert statements. eg. Cast(@myvar AS datetime) gets converted to Convert(datetime,@myvar). Any idea how that could be done in C#

Comment: You mean this definition of cast/convert: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx   They appear to be equivalent if you ignore style, so why do you need to change anything?

Comment: Yes but I need it to implement as a business requirement to match the standard. So I need to create a utility that will replace the Cast statement with an equivalent convert statement programatically

Comment: If there are only a few hundred of these, you will save time by just doing it by hand at 1-2 minutes each.    Are there more than this?

Comment: Yes a lot of them.

Comment: 1000?  10,000? 100,000?

Comment: If you have thousands of instances of this, they are likely to have a lot of variability.   Can it be "Cast(<complexexpression> as <longqualifiedreferencetotype>)"?  If so, are regular expression match (proposed in an answer) will not be effective.  You will need a matcher that can essentially parse <complexexpression> and <longqualifiedreferencetotype>.

Comment: @kayewan since you mentioned my answer was correct for the string you gave but not for all statements, you need to rephrase your question. There is no way we could give you an answer without a proper example.

Comment: Could you answer here ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463861/can-i-replace-all-the-occurrences-of-castsomevariable-as-somedataype-with-con

Comment: No, you can't get an answer there; the question is deleted.   This is a find place for an answer; you need to elaborate on the request.  I see you have a more detailed regexp answer; based on my guesses above, it won't solve your problem.  But only you can confirm this, and you can presumably only confirm this by looking at the "a lot of them" instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following Expression and use the capturing groups to get the pairs:

```
(?<=cast\()(.*)(?:\s+as\s+)(.*)(?=\))
```

[See at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/THzgfh/2)

```
var text = "Cast(@myvar1 AS datetime2)" + Environment.NewLine + "Cast(@myvar2 AS datetime2)";

var matches = new Regex(@"(?<=cast\()(.*?)(?:\s+as\s+)(.*?)(?=\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(text);

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    // first capturing group will be full match, so we need to start with index 1 for actual group 1
    var name = match.Groups[1];
    var type = match.Groups[2];

    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Type: {1}", name, type);
}

// Name: @myvar1, Type: datetime2
// Name: @myvar2, Type: datetime2
```

Comment: glad I could help